# Gaining root privs within LiveCD, for drive mounted in /media/[user]?

Tags: mount, permissions, lubuntu, gksu

So, here is my scenario, for a recent version of Lubuntu.  (I've tried tapping Lubuntu forums for help, that was a no-go.)

My hard drive is beginning to fail, according to the disk tool I load within the LiveCD environment.  Therein, I can mount the drive and access it from `/media/[user]`. I can navigate my usual folders, open media, etc... but I cannot copy it so as to rescue my documents.

How do I gain admin privileges?  I used to use `gksu pcmanfm` or `gksudo pcmanfm` but that was with the original drive already mounted.  I trust there is a slight variation to my needed approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing that isn't actually a root privilege issue - from my experience in data recovery, you can frequently still navigate the folders after you are unable to access the data.

Comment: Open a Terminal windows and type: sudo su . That meaning to switch to root user (with full admin right). Then type pcmanfm. Now you should have full read/write privileges over any and all media.

Comment: That's probably my thought, but when I try to copy and paste files from the newly mounted /media/, I am met with a denied-permissions prompt.  I am hopeful to find a way to open some kind of command line that tells the mounted /media/ drive, here's my password, give me read/write access... I just want to copy, please.

Comment: It would help to know the exact error message, but you could possibly fix the issue by remounting the drive with different owner and permissions. This might work: `sudo mount -o remount,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=000,fmask=000 /partition/identifier /mount/point`

Comment: You can use fdisk or lstblk commands (in Terminal). fdisk is older, lstblk is newer and more flexible. Or use GParted (it should be preinstalled in your livecd). Denied permissions may come from a hardware switch. Are you sure you have hardware permissions to write on that medium? You can't write on a livecd, even if the cd itself is rewritable. If you're trying to write on a sd card, make sure the side switch is set to unlocked.

Comment: @ipselute This might have done the trick!  I was able to copy to external storage, and the file wasn't corrupted.  Thanks!  And anonymous2, thanks for responding nonetheless!  I love this community.

Comment: @ipselute I'm making a note to reference your steps as you've mentioned.  And yes, not writing to LiveCD, but to an external source.  Seems to have worked in a way I can work with.  My idiot tax today is just time; I can live with that!

Comment: @WJRodrique: Please post your exact solution as an answer. There are over 70k unanswered questions on this site. Let's not make it worse! And if you accept the answer (even if it is your own) you'll get more reputation, your rank will go up, and you will get more privileges on the site, in time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting <s>bug</s> feature in ubuntu live-CDs(USBs): they require you to use root if you want to modify files on the hard drive. The joke is that root on live-CDs doesn't have a password! Therefore:

**SOLUTION:**

1. `sudo lubuntu_default_filemanager`
2. Press Enter
3. Perform rescue operations.